# How to loop through all documents in a View of IBM Notes (NotesView) with Java

Tags: java, lotus-notes

I have a View with more than 2 documents inside. This is the code which grabs the document

Currently I have this:

```
    Document orderRegelDocument = OrderRegelsVoorCopsView.getFirstDocument();
while (orderRegelDocument != null) {
//do something here
    System.out.println("Nieuwe Orderregel");
    tempOrderRegel = OrderRegelsVoorCopsView.getNextDocument(orderRegelDocument);
    orderRegelDocument.recycle();  // recycle the one we're done with
    orderRegelDocument = tempOrderRegel;

}
```

The first document is getting grabbed but after that I get a NotesException: Notes error: Entry not found in index viewName. What am I doing wrong?

And also a question next to this. If a user is in a document, but my agent also changes a field then when the user saves the document it gets a save conflict. Is there a  way to overcome this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are apparently doing *something* in the code that you are not showing that is altering the view before you are calling `getNextDocument`. You might be deleting the document, changing an item value that causes the document to no longer be selected for the view, or changing an item value that causes the document to be re-sorted to a different location in the view collection.

The idiom that is used to avoid this sort of thing is to make that call to `getNextDocument` as one of the first things that it occurs in the body of your while loop. I.e., just move it up so that it occurs before your `//do something here` code.  Like this:

```
Document orderRegelDocument = OrderRegelsVoorCopsView.getFirstDocument();
while (orderRegelDocument != null) {
    tempOrderRegel = OrderRegelsVoorCopsView.getNextDocument(orderRegelDocument);

    //do something here

    System.out.println("Nieuwe Orderregel");
    orderRegelDocument.recycle();  // recycle the one we're done with
    orderRegelDocument = tempOrderRegel;    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Richard. The documents in the view they have a flag field. If that field is set with value "0" then it is shown in the view. In the while I am doing a save document where i am changing that field for that document to "1" so that the document will be removed from the view.

Comment: That's the problem. Moving the call to assign tempOrderRegl = getNextDocument up to the top of your loop will fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know all of your code but my guess would be that assuming getNextDocument(document) gets the next and sets it in the document (otherwise you never assign it the getNext result to anything) you call getNextDocument() twice instead of once and you skip the second row and try to manupulate the 3rd (which is not present) and you get the error.

```
     if( OrderRegelsVoorCopsView.getNextDocument(orderRegelDocument) != null){  //Here you take the next
      tempOrderRegel = OrderRegelsVoorCopsView.getNextDocument(orderRegelDocument); //And here you take the next after 
      // Here you are at the wrong item already...
```

Comment: Updated my question please check.

Comment: By any chance, in the "//do something here" portion of the code, do you do something to the document that would take it out of the view?  That would cause exactly what you're seeing.  If that's the case, your best bet is to make a ViewEntryCollection from the view and iterate through that.